# Renaming directories in TortoiseSVN - conflicted state

Tags: visual-studio-2008, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I always have problems renaming a directory in TortoiseSVN.  It seems to be taking the correct steps, marking the original directory and directory files for deletion and adding a new directory with the new name.  I try to commit and get conflicted state and wound up checking out my whole project again.

Is this a known bug?  My workaround is to delete and add the a directory with the new name in discrete steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I some cases I found it to be easier to rename the directory directly inside the repository, by using the repository browser (in the context menu TortoiseSVN->repo-browser).

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give this a try.  After you do the rename, do you get the change into the working copy by doing an update?  Or you rename the working copy and the next commit works?

Answer (score 2):

Did you already try to use Tortoise's "rename" command?

[alt text http://jdecuyper.com/img/tortoise_rename.png](http://jdecuyper.com/img/tortoise_rename.png)

Comment: Yes, this is what I used.  I even made sure I was out of Visual Studio just in case of locks.  After I do a commit, my project winds up conflicted or locked or something that involves a minor headache.

Comment: Hi Steve, could describe all the steps you're following & copy/paste the complete error message? I tried to reproduce the problem but without success.